# Selecting Div Rows to highlight it one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[enter image description here][1]I am creating an examination appointment, and I wanted to highlight the selected row as green each time I clicked on it one at a time. The data in the rows are from the database. I tried to put class directly inside the div but the two rows were highlighted.

Thank you in advance

here's the output

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.selectdate', function(){


  var selected = $('#walakapake').hasClass("highlight");


$("walakapake").removeClass("row");
        if(!selected)
        {
            $('#walakapake').addClass("row highlight");
        }

  
 });
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
  

#table-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:500px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
  width:100%;

}

#walakapake:hover{
background-color: #fafafa;
}

.highlight { background-color: red; }

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>



</script>
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">

  <div class="container" >


 
<a name="submitting" class="selectdate" id="1">
<div class="row" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; cursor: pointer; " id="walakapake" >
      <div class="col-2 text-right">
      <br>
        <h1 class="display-4"><span class="badge badge-info">24</span></h1>
        <h2  style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="month_name" >NOV</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
      <br>
        <h3 class="text-uppercase"><strong>Examination day</strong></h3>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sunday  | 2019</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 8:00AM - 3:00PM</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item" style="color: orange;" ><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;" ></i> Slot  32</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Please bring your requirements</p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    </a>
    
  <br> 
<br>

<a name="submitting" class="selectdate" id="2">
<div class="row" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; cursor: pointer; " id="walakapake" >
      <div class="col-2 text-right">
      <br>
        <h1 class="display-4"><span class="badge badge-info">23</span></h1>
        <h2  style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="month_name" >NOV</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
      <br>
        <h3 class="text-uppercase"><strong>Examination day</strong></h3>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Saturday  | 2019</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 8:00AM - 3:00PM</li>
          <li class="list-inline-item" style="color: orange;" ><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true" style="color: black;" ></i> Slot  32</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Please bring your requirements</p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    </a>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at `.removeClass()`

Comment: I also tried that one, but the first row is only the highlighted part when I clicked into the 2nd row it stays on the 1st row :(

Comment: `hasClass` doesn't add a class; it is checking if you have that CSS class. You should use `addClass(your-css-class-here)`

Comment: Looks like his `.hasClass` was an abandoned attempt to define a boolean or the selected element. ...

Comment: I forgot to remove the .hasclass in my post. I already tried the addclass, but then the 1st row was only the highlighted one , when I select the 2nd row that first row still highlighted,

Comment: When I tried to refresh it, and select the 2nd row, still the 1st row is highligted.

Comment: try to remove all highlight classes first, before you set a new one:

$('.highlight').removeClass('.highlight');

Comment: Still, the same output is triggering, when I click the 2nd row, the 1st row is highlighted

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tuHT.png Here's the output, when I selected the 2nd row the 1st row is highlighted,

Comment: can you make your code as a snippet? That would make debugging it more easy ;-)

Comment: Ok sir , I will try

Comment: I added the snippet, :)

Comment: Thank you, sir Mario for the help, It was smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
$('.foo').removeClass('highlight'); //Removes every highlight
$(this).addClass('highlight'); //sets highlight to the clicked one
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="foo">Element 1</li>
  <li class="foo">Element 2</li>
  <li class="foo">Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This helps a lot, I just put the addclass and removeclass above the ajax code, to trigger it in every click. and change the click target to my div.